# Pandoc ignores Markdown-Headlines

Tags: html, haskell, markdown, pandoc

Using [snap](http://snapframework.com/), I wrote a splice creating text from markdown, using this function:

```
markdownToHTML :: T.Text -> [Node]
markdownToHTML = renderHtmlNodes . (writeHtml writeOpts) . readMarkdown readOpts . T.unpack
    where
        readOpts = defaultParserState
        writeOpts = defaultWriterOptions
            { writerStandalone = False
            , writerHtml5 = True
            , writerStrictMarkdown = False
            }
```

Now, when I, for example, give it this markdown

```
# Hi

Lorem ipsum something somthing

# Stuff

[a link](http://twitter.com/)
```

It produces this HTML:

```
<h1 id='hi'>Hi
</h1>
<p>
 Lorem ipsum something somthing

 # Stuff

 <a href='http://twitter.com/'>a link</a></p>
```

No matter how many newlines I put before the `#`, it is still just wedged into the paragraph.

Funnily enough, if I dump the same markdown into pandoc's [demo site](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try), it produces the correct Html output.

The full code of my project can be found [here](https://github.com/scan/neighr), if necessary.

Comment: It certainly does produce the correct output on the main site. Have you tried changing some of the flags? E.g. if you just use the default flags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the documentation for Text.Pandoc.  It says:

> Note: all of the readers assume that the input text has '\n' line endings. So if you get your input text from a web form, you should remove '\r' characters using filter (/='\r').

I suspect that's your problem.